# Add an argument to a protocol (delegate)

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, nsxmlparser, nsxmlparserdelegate

I want to add an argument to a delegate methode (From NSXMLParserDelegate)

this is the method so far :

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    // save the characters for the current item...
    if ([string   isEqual: @"off"]) {
         myObject.isON = NO; //doesn't know what is myObject
    }
```

What I want :

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string:(MyObject*)anObject{
    // save the characters for the current item...
    if ([string   isEqual: @"off"]) {
         anObject.isON = NO;
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: did you subclass NSXMLParser ?

Comment: No I didn't yet. Can I make a subclass and add my method ?

Comment: can you elaborate the exact requirement of having the object passed as an argument

Comment: Why isn't `anObject` an instance variable?

Comment: the object just have some strings and booleans

Comment: There can be some other ways of achieving this. It all depends on your requirement

Comment: I can't change the XMLParser delegate method , If i do that it will not be called

Comment: why not make "anObject" a instance variable using @property, so it is accessible all over the current class and in your method use it as  

`self.anObject.isON = NO;`

Comment: because I called the xmlparser delegates methods from an asynchronous request . It should know what object should be used or not

Comment: i would recommend restructuring your code but if you want to go with your current code you can try the 'objc_setAssociatedObject' using this you can add your 'anObject' to the 'parser' and access it later. 

see http://oleb.net/blog/2011/05/faking-ivars-in-objc-categories-with-associative-references/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to subclass your `NSXMLParser`, add new `delegate` property call it `subclassDelegate` or something similar, so you can differentiate between the super class's delegate. In init be the delegate of your superclass `self.delegate = self`;

respond to the delegate methods and forward the methods that you don't want to override to the `self.subclassDelegate` respond to the method that you want to override and override it in your subclass protocol.

Here is the example:

```
    @protocol  MyXMLParserDelegate;
@interface MyXMLParser : NSXMLParser<NSXMLParserDelegate>
@property (weak) id<MyXMLParserDelegate> subclassDelegate;
@end

@protocol  MyXMLParserDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser;
// this is the method that you override
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string withObject:(id)object;
@end
```

Then in .m

```
@implementation MyXMLParser

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        self.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}


#pragma mark - repspond to NSXMLParser delegate

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    [self.subclassDelegate parser:parser foundCharacters:string withObject:yourObject];
}
```

Comment: @Max Puis, do you like this solution ? have you tried it out ?

Comment: Yes I tried but it doesn't works . I can't set my delegate here :    MyXMLParser *parser = [[MyXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    [parser setDelegate:self];

Comment: what should I put instead of  [parser setDelegate:self]; ?

Comment: you create your myNSXMLParser and then, instead of  [parser setDelegate:self]; you do parser.subclassDelegate = self;

Comment: Thank you, but when I call     [parser parse]; should I do     [parser parse:myObject];  ?